# Json Data Stream to Cassandra using NIFI

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am new with Apache NIFI,I am trying to insert Data Stream to Cassandra Database using nifi,The json Data stream is coming from MQTT Consumer.

Anybody can help me please !

Json coming from MQTT is

*{"ip”:”1.2.3.4", "antenna":"01", “id":"80 88 3B", "time":"2017-8-20 18:31:59”}

{"ip”:”5.6.7.8", "antenna":"02", “id":"80 97 3B", "time":"2017-8-20 18:31:53”}*
*{"ip”:”3.2.3.9", "antenna":"03", “id":"80 45 3B", "time":"2017-8-20 18:31:52”}*

Cassandra table is

**ip | antenna | time | id**

Comment: but what is the question? look at processors `ConsumeMQTT` and `PutCassandraQL`  https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

Comment: @daggett My Question was How to split the json lines,and where to write the CQL statement ?Stream is coming out from ConsumeMQTT.I want to know the flow between MQTT and putCassandra

Comment: start from simple. for example do the flow `ConsumeMQTT -> PutFile` and see what you have inside messages. Also create another simple flow `GenerateFlowFile -> PutCassandraQL`, so you will understand what you should have in flowfile to store something into cassandra. Think how you should convert the original message from mqtt to be stored into cassandra.

Comment: @daggett  ConsumeMQTT -> PutFile and GenerateFlowFile -> PutCassandraQL both are working fine.please tell me which processor I should write the CQL statement to insert the stream.

Comment: I don't have any idea how CQL looks like. Please edit your question and add both: the original message and the CQL statement for this message with clarification that you want to know how to convert it correctly.

Comment: @daggett Please check I updated with Json Data and Table.

Comment: i don't know how to build valid CQL command. according to [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html) you can convert your message to kind of this query: `INSERT INTO table_name JSON '{"ip”:”1.2.3.4", "antenna":"01", “id":"80 97 3B", "time":"2017-8-20 18:31:59”}'`. the simplest way for this conversion is ReplaceText processor. Or you can put your message into an attribute(s) and use `?` in your query to link to attribute values

Comment: @daggett I again updated the question..If it is stream how the CQL will looks like ? and in ReplaceText processor which attribute I should write the CQL ?